# Uploading Big Files to Google App Engine with Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Im thinking of building an app for uploading large files to the GAE but I have the following restrictions:

The file upload can be stopped at any time and continued later.
The file can  be of any size.

I can have a client-side app, like an 'uploader app' that saves the state of the upload
but Im not sure how to do it

So my real question is, how to upload big files to the GAE with the posibility of pausing the upload (So the user can finish uploding tomorrow, for example).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the App Engine blobstore, unless you were to break the file into chunks, and upload each chunk separately. Files have to be uploaded all at once, or not at all.

This seems like a pretty unlikely use-case, though. Does anyone ever actually want to do this?

Comment: But what if the internet connection goes down for a sec. If hes uploading a 1Gb file, he'l lose everything.

Comment: @Woojah Yes. Most people who are trying to upload 1GB files aren't on connections that go down regularly, though.